# Switch statement in Swift allows duplicate case values. Is this feature or bug?

Tags: swift

The swift switch statement (tested in Xcode 6.1) allows repeated switch values. See code below which compiles and runs without error. Apparently, the first matching value is the executed case. Subsequent cases are ignored. Is this a bug or feature? If a feature, how is it useful?

```
class SwitchTest{

enum E {
  case one, two, three
  }

func test() {
  switchStmt(E.one)  // outputs: "one, two"
  switchStmt(E.two)  // outputs: "one, two"
  switchStmt(E.three) //outputs: "three, two"
}

func switchStmt(e : E)
{
  switch (e){
  case .one, .two:
    println("one, two")
  case .three, .two:
    println("three, two")
  case .one:
    println("one")
  case .two:
    println("two")
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's only a bug if the documentation says it does one thing but it actually does another. Anything where the documentation remains silent on the matter is technically only a disagreement between implementer and user.

However, in this case, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html) does *not* remain silent on the matter, it states quite clearly (my emphasis):

> It then executes an appropriate block of code, based on the ***first*** pattern that matches successfully.

The *reason* it's like this is probably to do with the fact that, unlike C, you're not limited to simple matches. You can provide, in the `case` stanza, single values, lists of single values, ranges, tuples, bindings, additional clauses like `where`, and the mandatory `default` case if you haven't already trapped all possible values of the type.

In that sense, it's quite logical. It's just a process of comparing the check value against every `case` stanza in order and executing the first match, regardless of whether it would match those below as well.

In terms of usefulness, that sequential nature will come in handy if you wanted to specify specific cases at the top and more general ones below, such as with the code:

```
switch num {
    case 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19:
        println("prime, 1 <= x <= 20");
    case 1...20: // don't need 1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20
        println("non-prime, 1 <= x <= 20");
    default:
        println("x < 1 or x > 20");
}
```

With the sequential checking nature and specific-to-general-case flow, you can simplify the later cases.

Comment: I edited your `1-100` to `1..<100`, as I'm sure you didn't mean `-99`, however it may be that you intended `1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 99`.

Comment: Thanks, @nhgrif. No, you got it right as per the text output.

Comment: Yea, a Swift switch statement is more to replace if... else if... chains and less like a C switch which was originally put in the language to mimic a assembler command.

Comment: To me, the "bug" is that `fallthrough` doesn't mean "keep testing" - it just falls into the next case even if there is no match. We need a keyword that _does_ mean that, so that you could conceivably execute multiple matching cases.

Comment: @matt, it's good that you quoted "bug", it shows you're aware that it's _not_ actually a bug. As per the docs: `The fallthrough keyword does not check the case conditions for the switch case that it causes execution to fall into. The fallthrough keyword simply causes code execution to move directly to the statements inside the next case (or default case) block, as in C’s standard switch statement behavior.` Your issue is simply a disagreement with the language designers. I've had plenty of those as well, but they're not bugs.

Comment: There are ways to do what you want, such as refactoring your cases with function calls: `case onething: doActionA(); doActionB(); case anotherthing: doActionC(); case athirdthing: doActionB();` which is equivalent to `onething` "falling through" to `athirdthing`. I would argue that `switch` statements should be like that anyway, to minimise large statements that are hard to follow :-)

Comment: Still, I think a keyword that means "now go on to the next tests" would make the cool ability to duplicate things in case patterns even cooler.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature--not a bug.  It's usefulness is made clear by less simple cases.

Consider this example from the official documentation:

```
let somePoint = (1, 1)
switch somePoint {
case (0, 0):
    println("(0, 0) is at the origin")
case (_, 0):
    println("(\(somePoint.0), 0) is on the x-axis")
case (0, _):
    println("(0, \(somePoint.1)) is on the y-axis")
case (-2...2, -2...2):
    println("(\(somePoint.0), \(somePoint.1)) is inside the box")
default:
    println("(\(somePoint.0), \(somePoint.1)) is outside of the box")
}
```

Consider that if `somePoint` had a value of `(0,0)`, all of the cases would be `true`.  And if the tuple were specifically `(Int, Int)`, the final case: `case (-2...2, -2...2):` could potentially be fully written out (25 combinations) in a comma separated list, more similar to your example.  We should want that to disallow our specific case of `case (0, 0):`, should we?

If we only define our cases in the way we're used to with a standard C-style `switch` statement, it doesn't make much sense... but then, giving multiple values in a single case isn't a C-style `switch` statement either.

The example in your question is a bad example of a good feature of the Swift `switch` statement.

---

It should be noted though that if we were to reorder the cases here, we could easily end up with `switch` where it's impossible for one of the cases to ever execute.  And it might be nice to get a warning generated if we build this sort of `switch` statement (for example, what happens if we move `case (0, 0):` right before the default).

But, consider that the following generates no warning:

```
for i in 2...1 {
    println(i)
}
```

It should, however, be noted that this will crash: `fatal error: Can't form Range with end < start`.

The point is, Xcode won't catch absolutely everything, so I'm not sure why we'd pick on `switch` statements.  A simple case like the example in your question might seem easy, but when we consider the totality of the complexity of Swift `switch` statements, I'm not sure I want a lot of time spent analyzing my `switch` statements like this.

Comment: `for i in 2...1` does not crash. `2 ... 1` is a *valid* range with start=end=2, it is equal to `2 ..< 2`.

Comment: @MartinR It crashed when I ran it.

Comment: Interesting. Which Xcode version? iOS, OS X, Simulator or device?

Comment: You are right, it crashes. Don't know what I tested  before. Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: Though, even if it didn't crash, the point remains that it would never execute and doesn't generate a warning.  Although any code inside a `while(false) { /* code */ }` block will generate a "code will never execute" warning.

Answer (score 0):

This should most definitely be a syntax error!
This will be the source of innumerable copy/paste errors.